# How do I deserialize JSON with optional properties?

Tags: json, serialization, f#, xamarin.ios, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize the following JSON:

```
{
  "listings": {
    "-L19C5OjcDSjMi4-oha-": {
      "listing_id": "-L19C5OjcDSjMi4-oha-",
      "location": "Edinburgh"
    },
    "-L19CJrzEpChO_W14YkC": {
      "listing_id": "-L19CJrzEpChO_W14YkC",
      "location": "Edinburgh",
      "messages": {
        "Rp7ytJdEvZeMFgpLqeCSzkSeTyf1": {
          "-L19V4QpPMCMwGcNaQBG": {
            "senderId": "Rp7ytJdEvZeMFgpLqeCSzkSeTyf1",
            "senderName": "Albert",
            "text": "Hey there"
          },
          "-L19r0osoet4f9SjBGE7": {
            "senderId": "YMM45tgFFvYB7rx9PhC2TE5eW6D2",
            "senderName": "David",
            "text": "Hi"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "-L19ChjPjX1DnfQb28AW": {
      "listing_id": "-L19ChjPjX1DnfQb28AW",
      "location": "Edinburgh",
      "messages": {
        "879dUqGuiXSd95QHzfhbSs05IZn2": {
          "-L1i6c7sGf3BcF2cCSCu": {
            "senderId": "879dUqGuiXSd95QHzfhbSs05IZn2",
            "senderName": "Alberto",
            "text": "Hello"
          }
        },
        "Rp7ytJdEvZeMFgpLqeCSzkSeTyf1": {
          "-L19FGCMuQACjYKCFEwV": {
            "senderId": "Rp7ytJdEvZeMFgpLqeCSzkSeTyf1",
            "senderName": "Albert",
            "text": "Hey"
          },
          "-L19T_v2Utxhu1mGhz7-": {
            "senderId": "YMM45tgFFvYB7rx9PhC2TE5eW6D2",
            "senderName": "David",
            "text": "Hi"
          },
          "-L19TbhActGmga4f47Mz": {
            "senderId": "Rp7ytJdEvZeMFgpLqeCSzkSeTyf1",
            "senderName": "Albert",
            "text": "How are you"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "-L19Cz1abm1o-JCbiAnN": {
      "listing_id": "-L19Cz1abm1o-JCbiAnN",
      "location": "Edinburgh"
    },
    "-L19DMdFx2pXj9-EKCq2": {
      "listing_id": "-L19DMdFx2pXj9-EKCq2",
      "location": "Edinburgh"
    },
    "-L19DV67WjguozFE_4dM": {
      "listing_id": "-L19DV67WjguozFE_4dM",
      "location": "Edinburgh"
    }
  }
}
```

In order to do so I have created the following records:

```
type MessageContent = 
    { senderId: string
      senderName: string
      text: string; }

type Message =
     { timestampId : string
       chatMessages : MessageContent;}

type Chat = 
    { chatPartnerId : string 
      Messages : Message array;}

type ListingContent = 
    { from : string
      landlord_id : string
      listing_id : string
      location : string
      name : string
      pic_1_url : string
      pic_2_url : string
      pic_3_url : string
      pic_4_url : string
      pic_5_url : string
      messages : Chat array
      postcode : string
      price_per_night : int
      to_date : string;
    }

type Listing =
     { timestampId : string
       chatMessages : ListingContent;}

type City = 
    { city : string
      listings : Listing array
    }

type AllListings = 
    { cities : City array;}

type SearchSettings = 
    { from : string
      location : string
      max_price : decimal
      min_price : decimal
      to_date : string;}

type MatchContent = 
    { id : string
      location : string;}

type Match = 
    {timestampId : string
     matchContent : MatchContent;}

type DeclinedContent = 
    { id : string;
      }

type Declined = 
    {timestampId : string
     declinedContent : DeclinedContent;}

type ListingUserContent = 
    { listing_id : string
      location : string
      messages : Chat array;
    }

type ListingUser = 
    {timestampId : string
     listingUser : ListingUserContent;}

type UserContent = 
    { declined: Declined array
      matches : Match array
      searchSettings : SearchSettings
      user_listings : ListingUser array;
    }
```

Next, I have the following line of code:

```
let listings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Types.UserContent>(html)
```

where `html` is the JSON string shown above.

However, this throws the following error:

`Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'Types+Declined[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'declined.-L0tmKVgUcj_a1ubO5Zd', line 1, position 36.`

I believe this might because there is no `Declined` in this particular JSON, however all of the 4 members of the `UserContent` Record are completely optional (they might all be there, or none of them might be there)...is this what I'm doing wrong? If so, how do I fix it, and allow for optional values.

UPDATE:

So I commented out the code which actually does the deserialization and I'm still getting the weird error, I don't think its related to my code

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the members of your `UserContent` record `Option` types, and add a `TypeConverter` for F# `Option` types, such as [this one](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2013/01/05/json-dot-net-type-converters-for-f-option-list-tuple/), to your JSON Serialization Settings.

```
type UserContent = 
    { declined: Declined array option
      matches : Match array option
      searchSettings : SearchSettings option
      user_listings : ListingUser array option;
    }

type OptionConverter() =
    inherit JsonConverter()

    override __.CanConvert(t) = 
        t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<option<_>>

    override __.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer) =
        let value = 
            if value |> isNull 
            then null
            else let _,fields = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(value, value.GetType())
                 fields.[0]  
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value)

    override __.ReadJson(reader, t, existingValue, serializer) =        
        let innerType = t.GetGenericArguments().[0]
        let innerType = 
            if innerType.IsValueType 
            then (typedefof<Nullable<_>>).MakeGenericType([|innerType|])
            else innerType        
        let value = serializer.Deserialize(reader, innerType)
        let cases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases(t)
        if value |> isNull 
        then FSharpValue.MakeUnion(cases.[0], [||])
        else FSharpValue.MakeUnion(cases.[1], [|value|]) 

let serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(JsonSerializerSettings(Converters = [| OptionConverter() |]))

use stringReader = new StringReader(html)
use jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader)
serializer.Deserialize<Types.UserContent>(jsonReader)
```

Comment: Its throwing this error now, `Expected JSON property 'Case'`

Comment: could you also please provide the code I have to use instead of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Types.UserContent>(html)`... I have a streamReader which converts the whole JSON into a string called html

Comment: Well, there are more issues with your record types not matching the JSON document.  My answer addresses the issue with optional fields, but it doesn't address any mismatches between your F# record types and the JSON you're attempting to deserialize.  It actually looks to me like the `ListingUserContent` needs to have an optional `messages` field, and that the elements in the `listings` node in the JSON map to that type more than the `UserContent` type.

Comment: I managed to fix those optional issues, but I'm still confused with how to replace the line mentioned above using the `serializer` instead

Comment: I have added the requested code to the end of the example.  You just need to create a `JsonTextReader` from a `StringReader` of your json content and then call `serializer.Deserialize<'record>(jsonReader)`.

Comment: I took a look at the Newtonsoft.Json source code, and that exception is thrown in `EntityKeyMemberConverter` while running `ReadJson`.  Are you sure you aren't still using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` somewhere?  I also looked at the constructor of `JsonTextReader` to be sure that can't throw, and I don't think it can.  Try doing a Clean/Rebuild of your solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163584/discussion-between-alk-and-aaron-m-eshbach).